# How do I change the size of the bounding box without it effecting the object selected?

Tags: mesh, objects, transforms, geometry, dimensions

[image][image: bounding box is bigger than imported image]I want to make the bounding box to have a nice fit around the object e.g the cube when you first open Blender.

anytime I import objects into blender, the bounding box seems to always be bigger the object I imported. I tried resizing the bounding box by pressing "N" and then the XYZ Euler and the dimensions the subcategory below it, but it always affects the object within the bounding box also.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot that shows the problem?

Comment: The bounding box should be the smallest "box" shape that contains all the vertices of the mesh. Could you provide an example of situation that doesn't fit with this defintion? Note that the calculation is based on the local coordinates, so if you rotate the default cube while in edit mode, the box size will be increased.

Comment: Look how the two vary, as the box pretty much "hugs" the cube compared to the yellow stick object I imported

Comment: @RonJab Can you upload the blend [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

I've had that trouble a lot with imported objects, and also those I've exported as .obj , and every time, it's been caused by some fragment of mesh that's somehow got into the project or obj file.  They've usually been a considerable distance away and expanding the boundary box significantly

The solution was to press 'A' to select everything in Object mode, then examine anything I couldn't account for that was hi-lighted.

You might have to search around in Ortho View in each of the three axis and also zoom back quite a way to see them.  Try ENABLING ALL LAYERS and pressing SHIFT-C to force the view to encompass every object in the entire Blender file.  Something foreign is in there otherwise the boundary box wouldn't be wanting to reach out to enclose it.

The offending item(s) are often unapproachable in that you cannot make them appear larger as you try and zoom in on them.  They can be just a dot.  Get as close as you can, select it, so it's the only object selected, and delete it!

I usually create my own models these days and haven't struck the problem for quite a while and have no files with that sort of stowaway with which to experiment again.  I'm sure those extras were separate from legitimate meshes because I don't remember ever having to go into Edit Mode to 'part' (P) them first before deleting them.

Hope this solves your problem - it's annoying when imported elsewhere because those fragments could be seen following the main object around like a distant bird, as though stalking!

Comment: nice one Edgel3D!

Comment: If the oversized bounding box is caused by an extra fragment somewhere, then the bounding box will hug the legitimate object automatically when the offender is deleted.  There might well be more than one.  I can't see any other highlited bits in your screenshot so I ask if you've got EVERY layer activated.  The offending piece might be lurking in another layer.  There are 20 of 'em.  (press Tildre (~) to toggle all layers on and off)